# htaccess won't work for directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

hello I am facing a problem with my htacess i have two php files that are used for URL rewriting first one is video.php and second one is channel.php. on homepage when I click any video its properly works for rewriting the url e.g.

> mysite.com/video.php?url=1234

changes to that works properly for me

> mysite.com/1234-video-custom-slug

but when I click for any channel it loads the same **video.php** but with rewriting urls of channel like:

> mysite.com/channel/1-channel-slug

instead of rewriting urls from **channel.php?id=1**

I don't know what i am doing wrong here is my htaccess file code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ video.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ video.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^channel/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ channel.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^channel/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ channel.php?id=$1
```

Comment: change the order of the rewriterule. Put channel.php rewrite followed by video.php rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order like this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^channel/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ channel.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^channel/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ channel.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ video.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ video.php?url=$1
```